# how to display a input box on safari with NPAPI plugin

Tags: macos, plugins, safari, npapi

As we all know, we can show input box with html element.like this.<\input type="text" name="" value="" >. but now I want to display this input box on safari with NPAPI plugin.
when I embed this plugin the box should show on safari. I found a npapi sample named "NPAPI Core Animation Movie Plugin" in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/NPAPI_Core_Animation_Movie_Plugin/Introduction/Intro.html . In this sample, it draws anything that will show on safari. But I want to know whether it is possible to use NSTextField to show a input box directly. Have anyone done the similar work?

Comment: please ,,waiting online @taxilian

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why can't you just use an `<input>` and send the value to the plugin?

Comment: because I want to make a soft keyboard.The plugin will display an input box and a button,when you click the button a soft keyboard will pop out so you can type the password on screen soft keyboard instead of the real keyboard. this is the function that I want to realize.@GeorgFritzsche

Comment: You can still do a soft keyboard with web technologies and thus easily cross-platform?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use NSTextField, or other native controls, in NPAPI on OS X. NPAPI is not designed for embedding native controls into a browser's window.

Comment: Yes ,so i choose to user NSLayer to draw a input.