# I must be shown in MAC OS NPAPI input box

Tags: cocoa, input, operating-system, npapi

I must be shown in MAC OS NPAPI input box.

But I don't know how to do it, I have set the basic framework, I want to create in the NPAPI or shows an input box.

NPWindow can convert HWND in Windows, but I'm not familiar with MAC, hope to get guidance:

1. how to create input box
2. how to create in the NPAPI
3. if you can't create how to solve, because I want to get the user input

It is better for the code, I thank you very much.

(My English is not good, please forgive me)

Comment: Not sure I totally understand your question; are you asking how to display a user input prompt from an NPAPI plugin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display a input box on safari with NPAPI plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772260/how-to-display-a-input-box-on-safari-with-npapi-plugin)